# How to filter through an array of objects and only get the objects whose entries do not equal any entry from another array's objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, filter, reduce

Basically I need to do an 'all except' option for when you are filtering table of products.
I have two arrays: `uniqueProducts` and `selectedFilters`.
`uniqueProducts` contains objects of products that are to be displayed in a table.
`selectedFilters` contains objects of the pre-selected filters.

Here's what an object of the `uniqueProducts` array looks like:

```
{category: 'radio', price: '50', manufacturer: 'sony', production_date: '2020/05/30'}
```

Here's what the objects of the `selectedFilters` array look like:

```
{type: 'manufacturer', value: 'sony', status: true}
{type: 'category', value: 'radio', status: true}
```

Because the price filter has min and max, I will filter through prices once I have the array of objects ready.

Filtering also does not include `production_date`.
So, the `selectedFilters objects's type` property can be either of the two above.

What I need to do is to filter through the `uniqueProducts`, and only get the objects that do not match any of the type and value of the objects in `selectedFilters`.

To put it differently, when you select filters for the products, and click 'all except', you have to see all the products that do not match that filter. Hope you get what I mean to say.

I've tried doing something like this:

```
uniqueProducts.forEach((product)=>{
                for(let i = 0; i < selectedFilters.length; i++) {
                    if(product[selectedFilters[i].type] !== selectedFilters[i].value) {
                        allExceptArray.push(product)
                    }
                }
            })
```

I've tried nesting `for..loops` too, and various other conditions, but the issue I keep running into is that, every time a particular property of an object DOES NOT match, it gets pushed into the array, even if the other property of that same object DOES match.

Can somebody help me figure out how to do the logic here?

Comment: do you ahve some more data (not just a single object) and the wanted result?

Comment: @NinaScholz All the objects in `uniqueProducts` and `selectedFilters` look the same as the examples above, just have different values. The property names are the same. The wanted result is basically an array filled with objects that do not meet any of the selected filters. So, for example, if there is an object inside `selectedFilters` whose `type` property is `manufacturer`, and its value is `sony`, then the `allExceptArray` array needs to be populated with all the objects from `uniqueProducts` EXCEPT those with a property `manufacturer` whose value is `sony`.

Comment: i would like to get an idea of the result set without description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following approach is based on a single [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) task where the reducer function incorporates a [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) based filter/comparison task.

The filter/match process is implemented in a way that a match is assumed as soon as the criteria of just one filter-configuration matches a single item property.

```js
function isMatchingItem({ type: key, value }, item) {
  return item[key] === value;
}
function collectNonMatchingItem({ filters = [], result = [] }, item) {
  if (
    !filters.some(filter => isMatchingItem(filter, item))
  ) {
    result.push(item);
  }
  return { filters, result };
}

const uniqueProducts = [
  { category: 'radio', price: '50', manufacturer: 'sony', production_date: '2020/05/30' },
  { category: 'radio', price: '70', manufacturer: 'philips', production_date: '2020/05/30' },
  { category: 'tv', price: '500', manufacturer: 'sony', production_date: '2020/05/30' },
  { category: 'tv', price: '650', manufacturer: 'philips', production_date: '2020/05/30' },
  { category: 'console', price: '900', manufacturer: 'sony', production_date: '2020/05/30' },
  { category: 'console', price: '700', manufacturer: 'nintendo', production_date: '2020/05/30' },
];
const selectedFilters = [
  { type: 'manufacturer', value: 'sony', status: true },
  { type: 'category', value: 'radio', status: true },
];

const result = uniqueProducts.reduce(collectNonMatchingItem, {

  filters: selectedFilters,
  result: [],

}).result;

console.log({ result });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

***Edit***

> *"... So, I need to now do the case when prices have been selected too and need to be all except filtered. I know I have to filter through the `result` array, but again, how do I make sure that only the objs that DO NOT match the min/max price are taken? ... My first instinct now is to just reverse the condition, i.e. do if NOT match, but then, what do I put inside? It doesn't feel proper to leave the if block empty. How should I go about doing it?" – user17144382*

The final price filtering of cause should be based on [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). Since the OP wants to filter every item where the item's `price` value is not within a certain min/max price range, one just needs to adapt the price value comparison accordingly. More important, [`filter` like most of the `Array` methods supports a second argument, the `thisArg`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#parameters), which gets applied as context of any filter function which supports `this` binding.

Thus it's not that difficult to come up with the additional implementation and usage of a properly named filter function ...

```js
function isOutOfBoundPriceRange(item) {
  const { minPrice, maxPrice } = this;
  const price = parseFloat(item.price);
  return (price < parseFloat(minPrice)) || (price > parseFloat(maxPrice));
}

function isMatchingItem({ type: key, value }, item) {
  return item[key] === value;
}
function collectNonMatchingItem({ filters = [], result = [] }, item) {
  if (
    !filters.some(filter => isMatchingItem(filter, item))
  ) {
    result.push(item);
  }
  return { filters, result };
}

const uniqueProducts = [
  { category: 'cellphone', price: '19', manufacturer: 'nokia', production_date: '2020/05/30' },
  { category: 'radio', price: '50', manufacturer: 'sony', production_date: '2020/05/30' },
  { category: 'radio', price: '70', manufacturer: 'philips', production_date: '2020/05/30' },
  { category: 'tv', price: '500', manufacturer: 'sony', production_date: '2020/05/30' },
  { category: 'tv', price: '650', manufacturer: 'philips', production_date: '2020/05/30' },
  { category: 'console', price: '900', manufacturer: 'sony', production_date: '2020/05/30' },
  { category: 'console', price: '700', manufacturer: 'nintendo', production_date: '2020/05/30' },
];
const selectedFilters = [
  { type: 'manufacturer', value: 'sony', status: true },
  { type: 'category', value: 'radio', status: true },
];
const  priceFilter = {
  minPrice: 20,
  maxPrice: 650,
};

const result = uniqueProducts.reduce(collectNonMatchingItem, {

  filters: selectedFilters,
  result: [],

}).result.filter(isOutOfBoundPriceRange, priceFilter);

console.log({ priceFilter, result });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I'll be damned! This actually worked great. Thanks man! So, I need to now do the case when prices have been selected too and need to be `all except` filtered. I know I have to filter through the `result` array, but again, how do I make sure that only the objs that DO NOT match the min/max price are taken? Here's a jsfiddle of how I did the ordinary filtering of prices: https://jsfiddle.net/w7e3k1v6/ My first instinct now is to just reverse the condition, i.e. do if NOT match, but then, what do I put inside? It doesn't feel proper to leave the if block empty. How should I go about doing it?

Comment: I did what you suggested in your code, but it's not working for me! I selected a min and max price, but those objects still get selected.

Comment: I also feel that it's a bit too complicated .. isn't there a more simplistic way of doing this? Like the way I suggested in my jsfiddle, since that's how I did it for the ordinary filtering.

Comment: The 2nd example code is not just a suggestion. **It is a prove** of the approach and its implementation. Since I don#t see your code, I can not tell what went wrong there.

Comment: When I select max price to be 50, only one object is left with a price of 92, but we have another object with a price of 150. Shouldn't both object remain?

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xLsepcvy/  keep in mind that I am doing this in react. Also, my point about your code being a bit too complicated has to do with the fact that this code is part of an assignment I am given for a junior position. So there's a bit of discrepancy between your part of the code and the rest.

Comment: @user17144382 ... again, there is no data in this fiddle either. No data no debugging.

Comment: What kind of data are you looking for? I can't give you the entire code for you to reproduce, it's too large, that's why I gave you the relevant arrays and objects. Why can't you just look at the logic of the code, and see if there are any errors. I thought the issue was that you are saying price > maxPrice, but if the price is 150, then 150 is not larger than 150, so I tried adding equal sign ,but it wasn't working either.

Comment: It works with my code that I gave you above that uses a simple if .. else. But the issue with is that the inside if block is empty.. so do you have any idea how do I make my code a bit better?

Comment: Got the point, I think my code needs to always parse any `price` values into number values. I will update my code accordingly. ... And it's hereby updated. Check it out. The code change does target the `isOutOfBoundPriceRange` function only.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I appreciate it. Can I ask you something? Your bio says you're a software developer, but do you work with vanilla JS, or do you use a framework? Also, how many years have you been a developer? I'm just asking because I am massively insecure.

Comment: nodejs is the development environment, always, regardless of frontend or middleware/backend development. I personally prefer to write expressive code in vanilla JS with JSDoc annotations. But I totally agree with and support the needs of and interests behind using TypeScript in e.g. enterprise code bases.

Comment: And how many years have you been doing this? I can tell you're very proficient in JS. I've done a lot of full stack projects with node.js too, but my main focus of interest right now is front-end and in particular React. I love React. My node.js skills are mostly basic. I can create my own APIs, endpoints, work with express, mongoDB and socket.io. I am interested in becoming full stack in the future, but not right now. I need to get better with the front-end first.